# How to find taxonomy name using only taxonomy TERM ID (or taxonomy term name)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

I am developing a multiple search filters function and I need to filter the search results page.

I have 3 custom post types, each one with its custom taxonomy. So I have the custom post types:

1. **CPT** books;
2. **CPT** fruits;
3. **CPT** cars

Each one of these custom post types has a custom taxonomy attached. So we have

1. **CPT**  books with **taxonomy** books-category
2. **CPT** fruits with **taxonomy** fruits-category
3. **CPT** cars with **taxonomy** cars-category

And each of these custom taxonomies have a couple of terms in them. So we have:

1. **CPT** books with **taxonomy** books-category, with **terms**: drama, crime, adventure
2. **CPT** fruits with **taxonomy** fruits-category with **terms**: apple, orange, banana
3. **CPT** cars with **taxonomy** cars-category with **terms**: mercedes, ford

In the searchform.php I have the search input AND a function that gets ALL the terms from ALL my custom taxonomies and puts them into a drop down.

So the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul> 
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="s" class="field s"></li>
    <li>Categories:</li>    
    <li>
        <select class="postform" id="cat" name="cat">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">All categories</option>
            <option value="99">Adventure</option>
            <option value="41">Apples</option>
            <option value="23">Banana</option>
            <option value="31">Crime</option>
            <option value="19">Drama</option>
            <option value="103">Ford</option>
            <option value="24">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="67">Orange</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" /></li>
</ul>
```

When a user leaves the search input empty, but selects a taxonomy term in that drop-down, I need the search page to filter my search results so that it displays only custom post types filed under that taxonomy term.

The big mystery here how can I find a way to get the TAXONOMY NAME to use in the WP_Query class, giving the fact that I have the TERM NAME and the TERM ID (the "value" field from my drop-down form). I could do this easy in taxonomy.php, but here I am in search.php!

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Best, 
Gabriela

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [`get_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) function? If you look at the code the sql it uses is as follows:

```
$_term = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = %s AND t.term_id = %d LIMIT 1", $taxonomy, $term) );
```

which should be exactly what you need!

Answer (score 2):

in the options value you could use something like this

```
<option value="tax_slug_a[ 103 ]">Ford</option>
<option value="tax_slug_a[ 24 ]"> Mercedes</option>
<option value="tax_slug_b[ 67 ]"> Orange</option>
```

the resulting form submission would give you an array with both chosen the tax slug info and the term id.